# My Ubuntu 20.04 computer can't ping or print to a printer on my local wireless network

Tags: networking, server, printing

I recently moved. After resetting up my printer and computer, I find that I can't print.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, and my printer is a Brother MFC-7860DW. My local wireless network is using a router supplied by FIOS (I don't think that's important, but my old apartment had Xfinity, and that's the only change in my set up).

My printer correctly reports the SSID it should be using (FIOS-XXXXX), and the IP address it has been assigned (10.0.0.150). When running diagnostics, it claims to have sent and rec'd the following:

```
 <Network Statistics>                  <WirelessStatistics>
 Packets Received       325             RX Frames Received OK   323
 Bytes Received      152703             RX Frames Error           2
 Packets Transmitted     56             TX Frames Transmitted OK 58
 Bytes Transmitted    17411             TX Frames Error           0
```

So, I *think* the printer is interacting with my router, at least.

My computer seems to see the printer as a service on my network

```
$ avahi-browse -a -v -t -r
Server version: avahi 0.7; Host name: Chanticleer.local
E Ifce Prot Name                                          Type                 Domain
: Cache exhausted
+ enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            PDL Printer          local
+ enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            UNIX Printer         local
+ enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            Internet Printer     local
= enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            PDL Printer          local
   hostname = [BRN001BA9F91290.local]
   address = [10.0.0.150]
   port = [9100]
   txt = ["TBCP=T" "Transparent=F" "Binary=T" "PaperCustom=T" "Duplex=F" "Copies=T" "Color=F" "usb_MDL=MFC-7860DW" "usb_MFG=Brother" "priority=25" "adminurl=http://BRN001BA9F91290.local./" "product=(Brother MFC-7860DW)" "ty=Brother MFC-7860DW" "pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL" "qtotal=1" "txtvers=1"]
= enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            UNIX Printer         local
   hostname = [BRN001BA9F91290.local]
   address = [10.0.0.150]
   port = [515]
   txt = ["TBCP=F" "Transparent=T" "Binary=T" "PaperCustom=T" "Duplex=F" "Copies=T" "Color=F" "usb_MDL=MFC-7860DW" "usb_MFG=Brother" "priority=75" "adminurl=http://BRN001BA9F91290.local./" "product=(Brother MFC-7860DW)" "ty=Brother MFC-7860DW" "rp=duerqxesz5090" "pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL" "qtotal=1" "txtvers=1"]
= enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            Internet Printer     local
   hostname = [BRN001BA9F91290.local]
   address = [10.0.0.150]
   port = [631]
   txt = ["TBCP=F" "Transparent=T" "Binary=T" "PaperCustom=T" "Duplex=F" "Copies=T" "Color=F" "usb_MDL=MFC-7860DW" "usb_MFG=Brother" "priority=50" "adminurl=http://BRN001BA9F91290.local./" "product=(Brother MFC-7860DW)" "ty=Brother MFC-7860DW" "rp=duerqxesz5090" "pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL" "qtotal=1" "txtvers=1"]
+ enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            Web Site             local
= enp5s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-7860DW                            Web Site             local
   hostname = [BRN001BA9F91290.local]
   address = [10.0.0.150]
   port = [80]
   txt = []
: All for now
```

But, I cannot `ping` my printer and it doesn't show up on `nmap`

```
$ ping 10.0.0.150
PING 10.0.0.150 (10.0.0.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.150 ping statistics ---
16 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 15360ms


$ nmap 10.0.0.150
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-24 16:31 EDT
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.06 seconds
$ nmap -Pn 10.0.0.150
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-24 16:31 EDT
```

At first glance, I think CUPS can see my printer:

```
$ lpinfo -v
network beh
file cups-brf:/
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
network lpd
network ipps
network https
network socket
network http
network ipp
direct hp
direct hpfax
network dnssd://Brother%20MFC-7860DW._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
```

Similarly,

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd
[sudo] password for smgutstein:
DEBUG: Querying "Brother\032MFC-7860DW._ipp._tcp.local"...
DEBUG: Querying "Brother\032MFC-7860DW._pdl-datastream._tcp.local"...
DEBUG: Querying "Brother\032MFC-7860DW._printer._tcp.local"...
DEBUG: sent=0, count=3
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x556af61f6c40, interfaceIndex=-1, protocol=-1, event=2, fullName="Brother\032MFC-7860DW._ipp._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=(nil), rdlen=0, flags=0, context=0x556af61f6180)
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x556af61f6560, interfaceIndex=2, protocol=0, event=0, fullName="Brother\032MFC-7860DW._pdl-datastream._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=0x556af61f85b8, rdlen=254, flags=5, context=0x556af61f6000)
DEBUG2: query_callback: "txtvers=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "qtotal=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "ty=Brother MFC-7860DW".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "product=(Brother MFC-7860DW)".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "adminurl=http://BRN001BA9F91290.local./".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "priority=25".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MFG=Brother".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MDL=MFC-7860DW".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Color=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Copies=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Duplex=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "PaperCustom=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Binary=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Transparent=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "TBCP=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x556af61f6560, interfaceIndex=-1, protocol=-1, event=2, fullName="Brother\032MFC-7860DW._pdl-datastream._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=(nil), rdlen=0, flags=0, context=0x556af61f6000)
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x556af61f6680, interfaceIndex=2, protocol=0, event=0, fullName="Brother\032MFC-7860DW._printer._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=0x556af61f8830, rdlen=271, flags=5, context=0x556af61f6320)
DEBUG2: query_callback: "txtvers=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "qtotal=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "rp=duerqxesz5090".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "ty=Brother MFC-7860DW".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "product=(Brother MFC-7860DW)".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "adminurl=http://BRN001BA9F91290.local./".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "priority=75".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MFG=Brother".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MDL=MFC-7860DW".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Color=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Copies=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Duplex=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "PaperCustom=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Binary=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Transparent=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "TBCP=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x556af61f6680, interfaceIndex=-1, protocol=-1, event=2, fullName="Brother\032MFC-7860DW._printer._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=(nil), rdlen=0, flags=0, context=0x556af61f6320)
DEBUG2: query_callback(browser=0x556af61f6c40, interfaceIndex=2, protocol=0, event=0, fullName="Brother\032MFC-7860DW._ipp._tcp.local", rrclass=1, rrtype=16, rdata=0x556af61f882c, rdlen=271, flags=4, context=0x556af61f6180)
DEBUG2: query_callback: "txtvers=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "qtotal=1".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "pdl=application/vnd.hp-PCL".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "rp=duerqxesz5090".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "ty=Brother MFC-7860DW".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "product=(Brother MFC-7860DW)".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "adminurl=http://BRN001BA9F91290.local./".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "priority=50".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MFG=Brother".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "usb_MDL=MFC-7860DW".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Color=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Copies=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Duplex=F".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "PaperCustom=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Binary=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "Transparent=T".
DEBUG2: query_callback: "TBCP=F".
network dnssd://Brother%20MFC-7860DW._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/ "Brother MFC-7860DW" "Brother MFC-7860DW" "MFG:Brother;MDL:MFC-7860DW;CMD:PCL;" ""
```

Also,

```
$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: MFC-7860DW
device for MFC-7860DW: dnssd://Brother%20MFC-7860DW._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
MFC-7860DW accepting requests since Sat 24 Apr 2021 04:06:38 PM EDT
printer MFC-7860DW is idle.  enabled since Sat 24 Apr 2021 04:06:38 PM EDT
```

But,

```
$ /usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp 10.0.0.150
```

yields no response, and although requests to print do not throw errors, neither do they print.

In order to check general network health, I tried `ifconfig` and `route`, with the following results:

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d0:50:99:7c:ca:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xfb400000-fb420000  

enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.158  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::25c2:3940:1906:7a6d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:50:99:7c:ca:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4279  bytes 4318473 (4.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 16  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2684  bytes 435733 (435.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 376  bytes 36871 (36.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 376  bytes 36871 (36.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         G3100.myfiosgat 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp5s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp5s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp5s0
```

But, now I'm sort of stuck. My printer ison my network. I can see it. I just can't talk to it. What should I do from here so that I can ping it and, more importantly, print to it.

Comment: Are you running two networks at home??  Your "ifconfig" shows  device "enp5s0" has an IP Address of "192.168.1.158", whereas your printer shows it is using ip address "10.0.0.150".  I suggest logging onto your router and determine which range of addresses its DHCP server is using... (I'd guess it's 192.168.1.X).  If so, then you will need to change the address that your printer is using (or the correct address of its gateway, if it is using DHCP)

Comment: Changing routers (from Xfinity to "router supplied by FIOS) IS where the problem is. Configure your router to allow the connection. Read `man traceroute`. Install and use `tracepath`.